# Why can't we use protected access modifier in Singleton class (object) for Kotlin

Tags: object, kotlin, protected, access-modifiers

Why can't we use protected access modifier in Singleton class for Kotlin .
We can use the protected access modifier in Java class but when it comes to kotlin , this does not work out .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't inherit from an object in Kotlin, so protected modifier does not make any sense. In Java, there is no such thing as singleton at language level, it's just a class with some specific logic

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin you cannot inherit from a singleton `object`, that's why `protected` modifier is useless, since `protected` modifier opens functions/properties for this class and  subclasses only.